# server view no longer shows server status

Tags: eclipse

In the display server view I have two servers listed. Both used to show the server status by displaying either '[stopped]' or '[started]' as well as showing if the server was started in debug mode.

Today - only one of the servers is displaying this information, so somehow, I've managed to turn off the display of this info for the second server.

How did I manage to achieve this and, more importantly, how do I turn it back on again - it's a pain not being able to see this info at a glance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show or hide the state and status of the server from the Servers view:

- Open the Label Decorations preference page: Click Window -> Preferences, expand General -> Appearance, and click Label Decorations.
- select or clear the Server State Decorator check box. By default, this check box is selected.

See [Showing the state and status in the Servers view](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/rwrcview.html)

Comment: Genius! That was really annoying me. Since there is no way I'd have accidentally turned it off through that route there must be a key combination that does it that I've managed to hit.